# Can't hook up Backbone model to a REST API

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js

What I want to do is implement a search functionality through REST API. For that I chose to have a separate collection for search results.

Here is what I have:

Collection:

```
var mira = mira || {};

mira.IndustrySearchCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: mira.Industry,
    initialize: function(models, options) {
        this.query = options.query;
    },
    url: function() {
        return "http://localhost:8000/manageDb/mira/industries/?q=" + this.query;
    }

});
```

Model:

```
var mira = mira || {};
mira.Industry = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

Here is how I am trying to perform the search:

```
    var result = new mira.IndustrySearchCollection([], {query: "Ag"});
    result.fetch({
    error: function(){
        console.log("Something went wrong");
    }, 
    success: function(){
        console.log("It werks")
    }});
```

The problem is that it always returns an error. What I expect it to do is to have multiple models in the collection and automatically bind attributes returned by the server to their actual values.

Here is the actual data returned by the server:

```
[{"id":2,"name":"Agriculture, forestry, fishing, and     hunting","code":"11","id_classification":{"name":"CAN_NAICS","id_country":"Canada"}},
{"id":3,"name":"Agriculture, forestry, fishing, and hunting","code":"11","id_classification":{"name":"MEX_NAICS","id_country":"Mexico"}},
{"id":4,"name":"Agriculture, forestry, fishing, and hunting","code":"11","id_classification":{"name":"CHN_NAICS","id_country":"China"}},
{"id":231,"name":"Agricultural implement manufacturing","code":"33311","id_classification":{"name":"JP_NAICS","id_country":"Japan"}}]
```

EDIT: Some more information:
It seams something goes wrong before `collection.parse(...)`, as I tried to override it and check the response but it failed with the same problem.

Comment: Did you specify `model` class in `IndustrySearchCollection` ?

Comment: @ArtemBaranovskii Yeah, sorry. I did.

Comment: What kind of error do you see?

Comment: Could you add argument in `error` handler and output it ? See my updated answer

Comment: @ArtemBaranovskii It just outputs the current object. I.e. `Object { length: 0, models: Array[0], _byId: Object, query: "Ag" }`

Comment: @ArtemBaranovskii `response.responseText` is `""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. I am sorry for wasting some peoples' times but the problem was server related. Specifically, it was a CORS issue, as my server was running on a different port(I thought different ports are still considered as from same origin).